# Autofill the model which have related fields to another model

Tags: python, django, django-models, web-applications

I am creating a django application and have created three models:

`models.py` :

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Listing(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    details = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    photo = models.ImageField()

class ListingDetails(models.Model):
    listing_id = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="auctioner", unique=True)
    owner_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="auctioner")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

`Listingdetails` have one to many relationship. One user can have many `Listing` . What i want is that whenever I create a listing the data in `ListingDetails` get automatically filled with the `listing_id` which is pk of `Listing` and `user_id` of user who created listing and `created_at` gets automatically filled with that time.

Comment: Can you share your full custom user model, which you've passed currently, and you should also define one field `user` in `Listing` model, and remove field `owner_id` from `ListingDetails` model, and also setting `listing_id` a foreign key with `unique=True` seems same as `OneToOneField` if you want, only one listing would associate to `ListingDetails` so you can make OneToOneField which will be better,  and remove unique=True in `listing_id`.

Comment: `AbstractUser` is imported from `django.contrib.auth.models` and I used unique because listing given by user will be unique. owner can have many listings but listing will only have one user.